# How to capture key events from Intent's or BroadcastReceivers

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, keyevent

Is there a way to capture a key event from the Menu button using an Intent or BroadcastReceiver?

Basically I want my app's Service to be activated when the Menu key is pressed.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just check the KeyDownEvent if the Menu Button was pressed:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.Callback.html#onKeyDown%28int,%20android.view.KeyEvent%29

Comment: I need to be able to capture this event without my app running. Hence why I'm wondering if there is a way for my app to be activated via an Intent or BroadcastReceiver :P

Comment: Ah ok now i understand. I dont think this is possible. And if, it isn't very userfriendly and I would really rethink if you want to do that.